# PostGres- How to loop in Table to update every record in Table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am working on complicated problem, but I will simplify it to this problem.

I have two tables

```
A [ID, column1, column2, column3]
B [ID, column1, column2, column3, column4]
```

and i want to update the third:

```
C [ID, column1, column2]
```

I am writing a query to

```
Select A.column1, B.column1 from A,B where  (A.column1 -B.column1)=1 limit 1;
```

Now I want to get all the points that

```
insert C(column1, column2)
Select A.column1, secElement from (Select A.column1 firstElement, B.column1 secElement from A,B where  (A.column3 -B.column3)=1 limit 1) as ex, A where A.column1=ex.firstElement limit 5;
```

But I am getting just one row.

I aspire to get a result like that.

- Loop on A
- for every element in A, I should find its peer.

But I couldn't find a way to do the condition. Take the element, look for its peer then go to the other element.

> A.column1 | secElement
>
> ----------+-------------
>   25033419 |      244959
>   25033420 |      244960
>   25033421 |      244961
>   25033422 |      244962
>   25033424 |      244963 
>   (5 rows)

I can express it algorithmically :

```
Foreach (element e in A)   //Global Query 
  Find_Peer(e)             // Query 1
```

UPDATE: 
I'm not in syntax. I am trying to get adapted to it. but it should be something like that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PointPeer(elem integer) RETURNS text AS $$
Select A.column1, B.column1 from A,B where  (A.column1 -B.column1)=1 where  A.ID=elem limit 1::text
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

Select A.ID, PointPeer(A.ID) from A limit 5;
```

I still struggling with the Syntax.

Comment: Huh? Try to set this out step by step, explaining what your first query is supposed to be doing, what you define as an element's "peer", etc.

Comment: In SQL, that's normally called a JOIN. Look up JOIN in a basic SQL book or web site training like w3school or something.

Comment: No ! It's not Join. I need to work on something similar to this (http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x20238_002.htm). Join give only one one record where we do the condition.

Comment: Check the UPDATE

Comment: Please remove some noise, only leave what's helping to define the problem. Will it be `(A.column3 -B.column3)` or  `(A.column1 -B.column1) ` as condition? 5 rows per elem in A or 5 rows per `A.id` or all peers? If just 5, how to pick? Please provide relevant table definitions including UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints - what `\d tbl` gives you in [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html). The syntax won't be a problem as soon as the job is defined in a way we can understand.